# IntelliJ Auto Complete File Path?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

A laziness/productivity question... is there a feature that allow auto completion of the file path?

So if I have

```
mainFolder
   subFolder1
   subFolder2
   subFolder3
```

I want it so that when I start typing path="mainFolder/

Then at this point I would hope auto complete to start telling me I can choose between subFolder1, 2, 3 etc...

Is this possible?

I'm using IntelliJ Idea

Comment: Where do you want autocompletion? It is supported for example in HTML oder XML files.

Answer (score 1):

I found that Intellij only autocomplete file paths that are a part of the project and there was no feature to autocomplete any path.

[File Path Autocomplete](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11088-file-path-autocomplete) is a plugin to do just that.

Disclaimer: I'm its author.

Comment: How to get auto completion in TypeScript file where I use something like ```/// <reference path='models/project.ts'>```?